# Problem with RubyGems/installing RubyOnRails on Fedora Core 7

Tags: ruby, rubygems, fedora

First of all, I'm *new* to Ruby.  Second of all, don't castrate me for running Fedora Core 7.  I'm at the mercy of GoDaddy's virtual dedicated servers :P

Okay, so basically, I've been trying to get Rails installed on my server for the past day, and I'm not entirely sure what the problem is.  Ruby and RubyGems are already installed, and a quick check shows their paths:

```
[root@ip-*** /]# which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
[root@ip-*** /]# which gem
/usr/bin/gem
```

So, according to like.. 20 different sources I've found online, all I would need to do is...

```
gem install rails
```

This is where I encounter my problem.

```
[root@ip-*** /]# gem install rails
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteSourceException)
    HTTP Response 302
```

Other sources have said I need to update my RubyGems, but this error duplicates itself when I try.

```
[root@ip-*** /]# gem update --system
Updating RubyGems...
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteSourceException)
    HTTP Response 302
```

Env data for RubyGems shows:

```
[root@ip-*** /]# gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - VERSION: 0.9.4 (0.9.4)
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - GEM PATH:
     - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://gems.rubyforge.org
```

Like I said, I'm a Ruby n00b, so any help would be appreciated.  I would really like to get Rails up and running on my system.  Thanks!

If you need more info, just let me know what I'm leaving out.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the current RubyGems and reinstall the latest version (it seems that you're stuck and unable to upgrade)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I ended up downloading RVM to help manage versions, and I was able to get the latest versions of Ruby, RubyGems, and Rails on my server.  Everything works great now :)